# mount tmpfs automatically on linux start up

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/tmpfs
# mount -t tmpfs -o size=6400M tmpfs /mnt/tmpfs
```

I ran that but if I was to reboot will I need to run that again because it is tmpfs?

How do I get that mount point to come back on a reboot?

Comment: For what purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual: You can define this in `/etc/fstab`

```
none     /tmp/tmpfs     tmpfs     defaults,size=6400M     0 0
```

Comment: I think however that you want /mnt/tmpfs instead of /tmp

Comment: can that be done with a software raid?

Comment: @ETL Sure, was just lazy with copying.

Comment: @JakeThomas Would you mind rephrasing your question? I have no idea what you want to know. How do you come from tmpfs to mdraid? But of course, `/dev/md*` devices can be (and usually are) configured in `fstab`.

Comment: you could also add the size option to your `fstab` example, so it will do exactly what he wants